Blazor Server with OIDC Cookie Authentication behide IngressControler in Kubernetes
I'm in trouble trying to use Blazor Server with authentication.
Running the application with authentication in the k8s cluster:

And I proxied the request using Fiddler:

And the log from nginx:
2024/06/06 18:34:13 [error] 15002#15002: *83248839 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.29.1.184, server: abc-powerapps-ondemand-web.dev.hbsa.com.br, request: "GET /_blazor?id=oS-BQBM6lnriZo-UZFmKsA&_=1717698793158 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.29.2.44:8080/_blazor?id=oS-BQBM6lnriZo-UZFmKsA&_=1717698793158", host: "abc-powerapps-ondemand-web.dev.hbsa.com.br", referrer: "https://abc-powerapps-ondemand-web.dev.hbsa.com.br/"

But a I have another app without authentication and It works as expected:

It is the same case as this one in StackOverflow: .NET 6 | C# | Blazor Server websocket connection failed after openid auth
I'm using WebScokets transport only:
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script>
        Blazor.start({
            circuit: {
                configureSignalR: function (builder) {
                    builder.withUrl("_blazor", {
                        skipNegotiation: true,
                        transport: 1
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

But I have already configured the annotions
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: abc-powerapps-ondemand-web
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: abc
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 100M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/large-client-header-buffers: 16 5M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 5M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers: 8 5M


I used big values to make sure it would be work rs

But it does not work :(
Does it has any other configuration do add ?
So, I tried it locally using nginx to try to figure out:
nginx.conf
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    proxy_buffers 8 128k;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    large_client_header_buffers 16 128k;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
}

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: web
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=abc-powerapps-ondemand-web

  app2:
    image: web2
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - app

And it work as expected. The same application
Follow the complete configuration generated from Ingress:
        server {
                server_name abc-powerapps-ondemand-web.dev.hbsa.com.br ;

                listen 80  ;
                listen [::]:80  ;
                listen 443  ssl http2 ;
                listen [::]:443  ssl http2 ;

                set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

                ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
                        certificate.call()
                }

                location / {

                        set $namespace      "abc";
                        set $ingress_name   "abc-powerapps-ondemand-web";
                        set $service_name   "abc-powerapps-ondemand-web";
                        set $service_port   "8080";
                        set $location_path  "/";
                        set $global_rate_limit_exceeding n;

                        rewrite_by_lua_block {
                                lua_ingress.rewrite({
                                        force_ssl_redirect = false,
                                        ssl_redirect = true,
                                        force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                                        preserve_trailing_slash = false,
                                        use_port_in_redirects = false,
                                        global_throttle = { namespace = "", limit = 0, window_size = 0, key = { }, ignored_cidrs = { } },
                                })
                                balancer.rewrite()
                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        # be careful with `access_by_lua_block` and `satisfy any` directives as satisfy any
                        # will always succeed when there's `access_by_lua_block` that does not have any lua code doing `ngx.exit(ngx.DECLINED)`
                        # other authentication method such as basic auth or external auth useless - all requests will be allowed.
                        #access_by_lua_block {
                        #}

                        header_filter_by_lua_block {
                                lua_ingress.header()
                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        body_filter_by_lua_block {
                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        log_by_lua_block {
                                balancer.log()

                                monitor.call()

                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        port_in_redirect off;

                        set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
                        set $proxy_upstream_name "abc-abc-powerapps-ondemand-web-8080";
                        set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
                        set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;

                        set $pass_server_port    $server_port;

                        set $best_http_host      $http_host;
                        set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;

                        set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";

                        client_max_body_size                    50M;

                        proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

                        # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

                        # Allow websocket connections
                        proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme     $pass_access_scheme;

                        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

                        # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
                        proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

                        # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
                        # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
                        proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

                        # Custom headers to proxied server

                        proxy_connect_timeout                   360s;
                        proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;
                        proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;

                        proxy_buffering                         off;
                        proxy_buffer_size                       5M;
                        proxy_buffers                           4 5M;

                        proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;

                        proxy_request_buffering                 on;
                        proxy_http_version                      1.1;

                        proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
                        proxy_cookie_path                       off;

                        # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
                        proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
                        proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
                        proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;

                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }

        }

